# Count does not work as expected in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel, count, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to get how many names do I have in database. For this purpose I am using Query Builder like this:

```
$namesIdsCount = DB::table('names_to_options')
    ->select('name_id')
    ->groupBy('name_id')
    ->havingRaw($having)
    ->count();
```

Is says that 24, which is not correct, because if I will write code like this:

```
$namesIdsCount = DB::table('names_to_options')
    ->select('name_id')
    ->groupBy('name_id')
    ->havingRaw($having)
    ->get();
```

result object contains 247 elements, which is correct. I have tried to play with skip/take, but still no results. Where am I wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the value of `$having`?

Comment: @Jerodev it contains my custom sql like `SUM(CASE WHEN option_id IN ({$optionSql}) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND SUM(CASE WHEN option_id IN ({$optionSql}) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0`, where `$optionSql` is a string with ids separated with coma.

Comment: first run the query with get() method, then count the values in the $namesIdsCount collection, i, e. count($namesIdsCount)

Comment: My first guess would be that the groupBy results in 24 groups, what Ali said, what is the count($namesIdsCount)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the other way around, you're not getting 24 groups.  You're getting 24 elements within the first group.  That configuration results in the following query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS 'aggregate',
    `name_id`
FROM `names_to_options`
WHERE EXISTS(
    {your $havingRaw sub-query}
)
GROUP BY `name_id`;
```

What you end up with will look something like this:

```
+---------------+---------+
| aggregate     | name_id |
+---------------+---------+
| 24            | 1       |
+---------------+---------+
| 5             | 2       |
+---------------+---------+
| 30            | 3       |
+---------------+---------+
| ... and so on | 4       |
+---------------+---------+
```

`Query\Builder` just doesn't realize you can get more than one result back when `count()` is involved.

You were pretty close to the right answer yourself though.

```
$namesIdsCount = DB::table('names_to_options')
    ->select('name_id')
    ->groupBy('name_id')
    ->havingRaw($having)
    ->get();
```

`get()` returns an `Eloquent\Collection`, child of `Support\Collection`, which has its own version of the [count](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-count) method.  So your answer is just:

```
$namesIdsCount = DB::table('names_to_options')
    ->select('name_id')
    ->groupBy('name_id')
    ->havingRaw($having)
    ->get()
    ->count();
```

If you really want this to happen in MySQL, the query you want to happen would look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT
        `name_id`
    FROM `names_to_options`
    WHERE EXISTS(
        {your $havingRaw sub-query}
    )
    GROUP BY `name_id`
) AS temp;
```

For that, you can do this:

```
$query = DB::table('names_to_options')
    ->select('name_id')
    ->groupBy('name_id')
    ->havingRaw($having);
$sql = $query->toSql();
$values = $query->getBindings();
$count = DB::table(DB::raw('('.$sql.') AS `temp`'))
    ->selectRaw("COUNT(*) AS 'aggregate'", $values)
    ->first()
    ->aggregate;
```

MySQL performance can get a little hairy when asking it to write temp-tables like that though, so you'll have to experiment to see which option is faster.

Comment: This is absolutely correct, thank you so much for explaining it to me!

Answer (score 0):

Inuyaki  is right

(id, name_id),

(1,1),

(2,1),

(3,2),

(4,3)

There are are four rows so get() method will return 4 rows

but there are three groups if you use groupBy [name_id]

1   (1,1)

2   (2)

3   (3)

now count will return 3

hope this will help.